# Android Web Request

Tags: android, json, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I am trying to send a JSON string to the server and retrieve back a resulting JSON from the web server. I am able to handle the posting part but not sure how to retrieve back the result in the same request.

```
private boolean sendFacebookDataToServer(String url)
{
    // conect to server
    // This method for HttpConnection
    boolean isDataSend=false;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("facebook", createJsonFormatDataString()));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);

        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse res = client.execute(request);

        String[] status_String=res.getStatusLine().toString().trim().split(" ");

        if(status_String[1].equals("200")){
            isDataSend= true;
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
    }
    return isDataSend;
}
```

Or is there any article i can refer to understand how its done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    String bufstring = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    isDataSend= true;
}
```

response data will be in bufstring

EDIT:

just replace your code(bellow) with my

```
    String[] status_String=res.getStatusLine().toString().trim().split(" ");

    if(status_String[1].equals("200")){
        isDataSend= true;
    }
```

Comment: should i stream for it after client.execute(request) ?

Comment: EntityUtils.toString will do this for you

Comment: cool.. so my JSON String from the server is stored in bufstring ?

Comment: it should ... but ... im pretty sure that your service will return 400(bad request) error not 200 OK :) ... but still you can use this code to read response and check what couse this error .... **why i'm so sure** you're sending `facebook={your json string here}` and i'm guessing that service expects only json string ... UrlEncodedFormEntity will set header with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and server can expect "application/json"

Comment: Oh ok.. how to set that part of the code to make it send "application/json"

Comment: `request.setHeader("Content-type",
      "application/json; charset=utf-8");` before request.execute ... but still youre sending bad entity ... try use `request.setEntity(new StringEntity(createJsonFormatDataString(), "UTF-8"));` ... but still you json can be malformed ... hehe ... but maybe application/x-www-form-urlencoded is good content type and insted of json you can use "smth=bla&smth2=aaaa" ...

Comment: is there any article or resource i can refer for the full lifecycle of the posting and fetching data from the server